# Unable to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, openvz

I've just installed MongoDB (standard Ubuntu build, not the latest stable) and for some reason I can't connect:

```
Mon Feb  6 03:11:22 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79
exception: connect failed
```

Now my machine isn't 127.x.x.1 it's for some reason x.x.x.2 (But i've changed my config to bind to that address, and also tried to bind to my public IP which provided no avail.

Config:

#mongodb.conf

```
# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 199.21.114.XX
port = 27017
```

I've checked the logs and only startup info is displaying in there.

I've also checked that the deamon is running too, and it is - I even tried running it manually with a `--fork`.

Has anyone come across this before? Or any suggestions?

Thx

UPDATE:

After a restart - here are the logs:

```
** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!

Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux allspice 2.6.24-28-se$
Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [initandlisten] *** warning: spider monkey build without ut$
Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Tue Feb  7 19:43:32 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
```

Comment: I should have added that I did try to mongo 199.21.114.XX:xxxx

Comment: Update - Use Docker and Docker-Compose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must specify the IP (199.21.114.XX), by running `mongo 199.21.114.XX`.

Otherwise, if you want it to listen on localhost as well, you should remove the `bind_ip` setting in your config file.

**Update** Check your firewall config. Since you're connecting to the external IP, it can be configured to block, even from the local box.

Comment: Added an update to check your firewall config, since you say you already tried specifying the IP in the command line.

Comment: At the moment there is no firewall config on there, as its an empty server.

Comment: Are you sure? If `netstat -a` is showing that you're listening on 27017, but you can't connect to 27017 (via mongo or telnet), there is probably a firewall. `sudo iptables -L -n` to check the rules.

Comment: Ah - I've checked and it doesn't appear to be listening on any port.... Any ideas?

Comment: Try restarting it and make sure the logs aren't throwing any errors.

Comment: Ok - Done that - I've updated the question with the logs - thx.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7430/discussion-between-stuart-sklinar-and-wes-freeman)

Answer (score 26):

I solved this problem by commenting out the following line in my `/etc/mongod.conf` file.

```
# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces. 
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

You will need to follow this config change with restarting the mongod process.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: I tried some of the other answers on here before this one worked for me. Is there any chance I will have negative consequences in the future from deleting mongod.lock or allowing input and output on port 27017 in my ip tables?

Comment: Commenting out `#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` will open it to anyone/anywhere. Make sure you either has your firewall/iptables filtering unsolicited connections and/or add `security:  authorization: 'enabled'`
in your `/etc/mongod.conf`. Else, anyone/anywhere can write to your DB.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Comment: ditto -- ok maybe not my life but definitely an hour of my time :)

Comment: This worked for me.  Had to restart mongod afterwards.  sudo service mongodb restart.

Comment: after a long journey , I ended up with your answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue just because the silly mistake.

first remove mongodb file which is fine

```
rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

where I did mistake inside the /etc/mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
 #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
bindIp: privateIp
```

instead of

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 10.1.2.4
```

for listen to all available ips

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,10.128.0.2]
```

restart the mongodb

```
sudo service mongod start
```

hopefully this answer help for someone

Comment: i think you meant ```sudo service mongodb start```. also it didn't work for me with the brackets or with spaces after the commas. so mine was like this: ```bind_ip: 127.0.0.1,192.168.222.222```

Answer (score 3):

in  /etc/mongod.conf

I changed,

`bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

to

`bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

which is all ports. Yeah, I know it's risky, but I am running on an internal network.

BTW commenting out `#bindIp: 127.0.0.1` did NOT work for me, running under Ubuntu 18.

Comment: This worked for be using Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 2):

By default, running the `mongo` console command will look for mongodb on your localhost, hence the `127.0.0.1` IP which is your local loopback. Also, the default config for `mongod` should be available on localhost. Its better to do it this way for now to start, unless you have turned on auth. Make sure you have auth enabled or your database is running openly on your public ip.

When you want to connect to a host other than localhost or your default config, you do:

```
mongo <host>
```

Answer (score 2):

following steps may help you :

1. open terminal and run "***sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock***"
2. now run " **sudo mongod --repair** "
3. now "***sudo start mongodb***"
4. now just check the status of mongodb status "***sudo status mongodb***"

5 lastly just invoke command "***mongo***"

Comment: It's "sudo status mongod"

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this when `mongod` was running but not yet running "properly". I'm guessing there is probably a better way to wait for it to come up after installation, but adding a `sleep 10` seems to fix it.

A slightly less cavemanly approach might be to `tail -f` its log file and look for the event where it tells you that it is listening on the interface you specified.

```sh
local log=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
sudo -u mongodb touch "$log"
service mongod start &
launcher=$!
tail -0f "$log" |
grep -q 'port: 27017'
wait "$launcher"
sleep 1
```

The final `sleep` is a bit of an act of desperation; it seems to take a jiffy after it logs the startup until it's properly up and listening.

See also [Bash shell script not getting connect to MongoDB even if status is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601922/bash-shell-script-not-getting-connect-to-mongodb-even-if-status-is-active/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add mongod option param bind_ip

```
mongod -–help
```

--bind_ip arg                         comma separated list of ip addresses to
                                        listen on - localhost by default

--bind_ip_all                         bind to all ip addresses

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, run the services
then check mongoDB server is running, if not running, Start it.

mongoDB server by default run on localhost:27017. 
Click localhost:27017 the create an admin user first.