# Bash shell script not getting connect to MongoDB even if status is active

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04. I have the following bash script to install and run the MongoDB. IT checks if MongoDB is installed or not and run some mongo shell commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /usr/bin/mongod ]; then
          echo "MongoDB is installed on your machine."
            kill -0 "$$" || exit
else
            password=password
            echo "********************* MongoDB 4.0 INSTALL **************************"
            echo "MongoDB is is not installed."

            echo "******************************************************************"
            echo $password | sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 68818C72E52529D4

            echo $password | sudo bash -c "echo deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
            sudo bash -c "apt update && apt upgrade -y"
            sudo bash -c "apt-get install -y mongodb-org"

            sudo bash -c "apt update && apt upgrade -y"
            echo 'y' | sudo bash -c "apt autoremove && apt clean"

            sudo bash -c "mkdir /data /data/db"

            sudo bash -c "systemctl enable mongod"  #enables Mongo on system startup
            sudo bash -c "service mongod start"
            sudo bash -c "service mongod restart"

            kill -0 "$$" || exit

            echo "********************* MongoDB Create DB and Collection **************************"
fi
mongod_status=`systemctl is-active mongod`
echo "${mongod_status}"

if [[ "${mongod_status}" == "active" ]]
then
            echo "MongoDB is already running."
    else
            echo "MongoDB is not running"
            rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
            sudo bash -c "service mongod start"
    fi
mongo <<EOF
        use fragment
        db.createCollection("fragmenthash");
EOF
```

If my system is not installed with MongoDB, this script installs and start it. Then it checks the status, which is "active". But then when it executes `mongo <<EOF section`, it returns

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-05-19T10:06:01.134+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:356:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Even if the status of MongoDB is Active still it gives this error. Whereas, if MongoDB is already installed, it executes the whole script successfully with creating DB and collection. Please help.

Comment: No offense, but that's some really messy shell scripting there. What do you hope `kill -0 "$$" || exit` would do?

Comment: I followed some tutorial. Now, I tried without ```kill -0 "$$" || exit```. Still same issue

Comment: The `kill` is not your problem but I honestly cannot imagine what it's supposed to do. As far as I can tell, it basically does nothing: the `kill` succeeds when the parent process exists, which it probably does, and so then that's the end of it. (`kill -0` doesn't really send a signal, it just checks if the process is alive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has a number of oddities which should probably be straightened out regardless of the immediate problem.

- `kill -0 "$$" || exit 0` is weird and probably does nothing useful. I *guess* you probably simply should do nothing in this case, as the purpose of the script seems to be to install the component if it's missing, and then proceed into the `mongodb_status=` ... part.
- As basically all the commands here are privileged, it would make more sense to just abort up front if the entire script is not running with privileges.

Stylistically, everything which looks like `sudo bash -c 'singlecommand'`  should be just `sudo singlecommand`; but with the proposed refactoring, you don't need these at all.

The immediate problem with your script seems to be that it takes a while for the server to start listening on the port you configured it for. I don't know enough about Mongo to tell you how to properly wait for it to tell you when it's up "for real" but adding a `sleep` is a common (albeit crude) workaround.  Another is to examine the log file, looking for the listening event.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Test for privileged access
test -w / ||
{ echo "$0: need to run privileged; aborting" >&2; exit 127; }

startit () {
    local log=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
    service mongod start
    while true; do
        test -e "$log" && break
        sleep 1
    done
    grep -q 'port: 27017' "$log" ||
    tail -0f "$log" |
    grep -q 'port: 27017'
}

if [ -f /usr/bin/mongod ]; then
    # Send diagnostic messages to standard error
    echo "$0: MongoDB is installed on your machine." >&2
else
    # Reduce eyesore
    echo "$0: MongoDB is not installed; proceed with 4.0 install" >&2
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 68818C72E52529D4
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
    apt update && apt upgrade -y
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org
    # not necessary or useful to do a second time
    # apt update && apt upgrade -y
    apt -y autoremove && apt clean
    mkdir -p /data/db
    systemctl enable mongod
    startit
    # service mongod restart  # is this really useful and necessary?
fi
echo "$0: database initialization" >&2

# Prefer modern command substitution syntax
mongod_status=$(systemctl is-active mongod)
echo "$mongod_status" >&2

if [[ "${mongod_status}" == "active" ]]
then
    echo "$0: MongoDB is already running." >&2
else
    echo "$0: MongoDB is not running" >&2
    rm -f /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
    startit
fi

mongo <<EOF
        use fragment
        db.createCollection("fragmenthash");
EOF
```

I'm not entirely happy with the `startit` function -- at first it failed because I tried to open the log file when it did not yet exist, then it failed because the new lines in the log file already contained the startup message after the one-second sleep. Now it could still fail if the log file is being appended and the old logs contain the startup message from a previous session. But at least this should get you started in the right direction, I hope.

Here's a refactoring which *might* be more robust ...

```sh
startit () {
    local log=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
    sudo -u mongodb touch "$log"
    service mongod start &
    local launcher=$!
    tail -0f "$log" |
    grep -q 'port: 27017'
    wait "$launcher"
    sleep 1
}
```

The final `sleep` is a bit of an act of desperation; it seems to take a jiffy after it logs the startup until it's properly up and listening; and/or maybe add a retry loop around the final `mongo` command.

Comment: Also added the second snippet to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635646/874188

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code. I tried your script. After installing the MongoDB, it is not getting connected and the part ```mongo <<EOF``` is not executed. Same problem.

Comment: I dunno, I actually set up a Docker container to test this and it worked for me. But it's been a week already and I scrapped it so I have no easy way to go back and check. Probably your code needs some additional things in order to do anything; once again, try to create a [mre].

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Comment: Actually not Docker because it requires `systemd` ... I guess I did that in Virtualbox.  And two weeks ago already.

Comment: I recreated it and it worked again. Which version of the `startit` function did you use?

Comment: I tried both. I tried ```sleep 5``` just before ```mongo <<EOF```. IT works!

Comment: Oh, there was a bug in the `grep` in the second version. I hope this should be reliable now.

Comment: Sorry, not working at my side. This makes the installing process stuck on halt. Then I stop and run the script again. It again goes on halt with MongoDB status failed.

Comment: I guess the ```sleep``` is resolving the main problem in my code.

Comment: Could you run it with `grep -m 1` instead of `grep -q` and show the output of (the end of) `sudo bash -x scriptname`?

Comment: Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
+ apt -y autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
+ apt clean
+ mkdir -p /data/db
+ systemctl enable mongod
+ startit
+ local log=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
+ touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
+ local launcher=15289
+ service mongod start
+ tail -0f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
+ grep -m 1 'port: 27017'. It gets stuck here.

Comment: I updated the `touch` too, it needs to create the log file as user `mongodb`.

Comment: Yeah! It is working! Thank you! Please update the answer with the ```grep -m 1```. I will accept.

Comment: `grep -q` does the same as `grep -m 1`, it's just that you see what it's doing (which you don't want once the code actually works).